# Url redirection on OnActionExecuting method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, httpcontext, onactionexecuting

We are trying to implement a non-hosted header that will accept anything before `*.website.com` in ASP.NET. Since it will accept any subdomain, we extended the HttpContextBase class to add custom method.

```
public static bool ValidateHost(this HttpContextBase context)
{
    var domain = context.Request.Url.Host;

    //add logic to check if the host is valid and the subdomain exist in the database

    return false;
}
```

This method will validate whether the `context.Url.Host` is a valid host or its subdomain exist in the database if not then redirect the request to the default host `website.com`. To do that I added this line of codes below in our `BaseController`:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (!filterContext.HttpContext.ValidateUrl())
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("https://website.com/");
        return;
    }
}
```

It redirects to default host whenever it returns `false`, however it throws an exception: `{"Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent."}`

Am I missing something here or the logic is incomplete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try RedirectResult

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("https://website.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTTP there is always single response for each request. So this error means that you've already send something to response and again you are requesting for other URL.